# I can see my all attributes in storyboard but not in Simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am using xcode 6.1 and developing in Swift. My storyboard and all simulator is behaving in different way. I can see attributes (like textfield, label etc..) in storyboard but not in simulator.

Somehow I can't attach the snapshot.

Comment: More information is required to be able to assist you

Comment: Without screenshot it's hard to find solution still cross check your viewcontroller class that you have set and all stuff.

Comment: thanks i have checked that too..i have got the solution from story board.Actually storyboard size was not set properly so i have reset that it works fine in simulators....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't added the layout constraints.

Check you Auto Layout constraints. Because of that it might be not displaying your Elements properly on your simulator.

Here are the few links from where you can start learning the auto-layout.

1. [iOS Developer Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW1)
2. [Tutorial for Autolayout](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Comment: Hi Femina, got the solution ...Storyboard was creating a problem for me..i have reset its size and its looks perfect now....